# Get dropdown value when selected and pass it to controller without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I have 2 dropdown lists, CATEGORY and SUBCATEGORY. SUBCATEGORY will vary on what value will be selected on CATEGORY. What I want to do is to get the value id and pass it to my controller. Once I get the value in my controller, I'll send it to my model and all the data which is equivalent to my CATEGORY_ID will be displayed in SUBCATEGORY. How can I do that? I'm stucked in getting the value of the dropdown on change using javascript. I'm trying to use ajax but have no luck. It's in a bootstrap modal.

Example:

### If I select:

CATEGORY = FOOD

SUBATEGORY = Cake, Vegetables. Fruits, etc.

CATEGORY = SPORTS

SUBATEGORY = Basketball, Volleyball, etc.

### Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Here's my two dropdown lists in modal(view):

CATEGORY

```
<select name='category_uuid' id="category_uuid">
<?php
  foreach($categories as $categories):
   if ($form_action=="update") {
    echo "<option value='".$category_uuid."' ".(($category_uuid == $categories->uuid) ? 'selected':'').">".$categories->name."</option>";
}else{ 
    echo "<option value='".$categories->uuid."'>".$categories->name."</option>";
    }
    endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

MY SCRIPT

```
<script>
$("#category_uuid").change(function(){
$.ajax({
 type : 'POST',
 data : 'cat_id='+ $("#category_uuid").val(),
 url : 'questions/form',
 success : function(data){
             $('#data').val(data);
 }
});
}); 
</script>
```

SUBCATEGORY

```
<select name="subcategory_uuid" id="subcategory_uuid">
<?php                           
  foreach($subcategories as $subcategories):
if ($form_action=="update") {
 echo "<option value='".$subcategory_uuid."' ".(($subcategory_uuid == $subcategories->uuid) ? 'selected':'').">".$subcategories->name."</option>";
}else{ 
 echo "<option value='".$subcategories->category_uuid."'>".$subcategories->name."</option>";
}
endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Show some of the code that you are having difficulty with.

Comment: @StBlade Done. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you may need to change it accordingly:
Your Js:

```
$("#category_uuid").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
     type       : 'POST',
     data       : { cat_id : $("#category_uuid").val() } ,
     url        : '<?=base_url()?>questions/subCat',
     success    : function(data){
                 $('#subcategory_uuid').val(data);
     }
    });
});
```

Your controller:

```
function subCat(){
    if( $this->input->post( null ) ){
        $id            = $this->input->post('cat_id', true);
        $data['cat']   = $this->model->get_all_sub_categories( $id );
        echo $this->load->view('ajax_categories', $data, true );
    }
}
```

Your Model:

```
function get_all_sub_categories( $id ){
    return $this->db->select('id, name')->where_in('column_id', $id)->get('table_name')->result_array();
}
```

Your view `ajax_categories`:

```
if( isset( $cat ) && is_array( $cat ) && count( $cat ) > 0 ){
    foreach( $cat as $key => $each ){
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nil'z, I'll try it now and tell if it's working. :)

By the way, I'm using function _remap in my controller. Will it affect anything?

Comment: have you changed the model and view files accordingly?